# Build Failed. See the build log for detail

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, build, msbuild

I create a new project, click compile, and get this error:

> Build Failed. See the build log for details.

In the build log there is only this:

```
Building: FirstProgram (Debug|x86)

---------------------- Done ----------------------

Build failed.
Build: 1 error, 0 warnings
```

Here is what I see:

[image]

What causes this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: There is an Output window/panel in Xamarin Studio that should show you the messages from the Build command.  What do they say?

Comment: I added a picture to the post. Are you referring to that window as the output window Jason? Leo How do I find the log?

Comment: dont show error Instead show output window log

Comment: I am sorry but how do I show the output window log?  I googled it and there should be an "application output" tab in the bottom right but mine isn't there.

Comment: Nevermind I made the "Android Log" show up. Nothing appears in the log though..

Comment: Also if it helps any.. the emulator won't launch when debugging. I can launch it manually though. Perhaps something is wrong with how it is configured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded and installed the packages shown below in the order listed:

1. JDK 1.6: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk-6u31-download-1501634.html Please choose the jdk-6u31-windows-i586.exe installer from the list above.
2. Android SDK: http://dl.google.com/android/installer_r20-windows.exe After the main installer is done, please open the SDK Manager and install the following platform APIs: 7,8,10,12,14
3. Mono for Android SDK: http://download.xamarin.com/MonoforAndroid/Windows/mono-android-4.4.55.104956787.msi
4. Reboot Xamarin.

Answer (score 20):

Lots of times dealing with this error. I just closed and reopened. It happens every time I add a solution and then delete it. I think Xamarin Ide is not a really good Ide, not in Mac at least.

Comment: This also worked for a non-xamarin project that I'm working on.

Comment: Working on a Tizen .NET app and this happens every time I close a solution that I have open in the same workspace. Frustrating!

Answer (score 2):

In my case, i did`t Indy (or higher) License.
When i started trial period, the problem was solved.
[image: start trial]

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when trying to build. Without having noticed I had been logged out of my account, which caused the error. Curious that I wasn't prompted to relog or given information that I wasn't logged in.

Answer (score 1):

Though this is an old post, maybe this could help someone.
In my case, using Xamarin Studio 6.1.4 (build 1), I unchecked
the 'Use MsBuild engine ...' check box under *Project Options > Build > General* and
the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I searched for solution online for similar problem, but none solved my problem, then I tried this:
`Tools >>> Options >>> Projects and Solutions >>> Build and Run`
Then I changed `MSBuild output` and `MSBuild log` to `Detailed`.
Rebuild and the error message will show.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`cd` into the project path, and hit `msbuild` on it.
You will then see the error details in the console STDOUT.

Comment: In an interesting spin, actually running msbuild stopped the error in the IDE and I could then build and run!

Comment: bizare but I think this fixed it for me as well -- ran msbuild manually, restarted IDE, now it builds.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue today in Visual Studio for Mac 2022 with a Xamarin Forms 5 project. In my case, going to the Solution properties, under Build → General, and *un*checking "Build with MSBuild on Mono" worked.

[image]

(This might be similar in spirit as [@JackGriffin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42031382/4751173), but it seems to be a *solution* property rather than a *project* property.)

Comment: this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after upgrading Xamarin, and in my case it happened even for a x86/desktop Console Application. Turned out to be because I didn't have 4.5.1, which was required by the newer version (I had only 4.5 I think).

I found this entry in the log:

```
Unregistered TargetFramework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1' is being requested from SystemAssemblyService, returning empty TargetFramework
```

After googing this error I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/38102386/492336, and the solution was to download .NET 4.5.1 and it worked after that!

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem using Visual Studio Community for Mac.  The system was out of disk space.  Freeing up some disk allowed a build to complete successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following options from *Build* menu:

- *Clean All*
- *Rebuild All*

Then build it again.

---

If won't help, check your log files for details by going to *Help* menu and *Open Log Directory*.

For example by dragging & dropping the log folder into newly opened *Terminal* window, and run:

```
tail -f *.log
```

then run the build again and check the reported logs. Hit <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> on *Terminal* when finished.

For better visibility, run:

```
tail -f *.log | grep -C5 -i error
```

---

You can also try to clear cache folder of `VisualStudio`, e.g.:

```
$ lsof -p $(pgrep VisualStudio)
$ rm -fr ~/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.visual-studio
```

Answer (score 0):

Try building your project from the Powershell command line.

```
dotnet build
```

Then, build errors will appear in the command line output.