# Xamarin Studio's intellisense behaves badly for LINQ queries

Tags: c#, linq, intellisense, xamarin-studio

When I enter a LINQ query in Xamarin Studio 5.10.3 (build 51), auto-complete starts suggesting things incorrectly, for example in `join s in doc.Descendants("Supplier")` it will auto-correct `s` to `sim`:

[image]

Or in `on (int)p.Attribute("SupplierID")`, it will auto-correct `(int)` to `(into)`. These constant wrong auto-corrections make it difficult to write LINQ queries in MonoDevelop.

Is it possible to fix the intellisense so it works properly? If not, can it at least be turned off for LINQ queries so I don't have to constantly return and undo wrong auto-corrections?

Comment: have you tried the latest version 6.x?

Comment: @JakubHolovsky Is it free to download? I had originally tried to download MonoDevelop from http://www.monodevelop.com/download/, which redirected me to `Xamarin Studio 5.10.3 (build 51)`. I tried downloading Xamarin Studio, but it starts asking questions about company size etc. I had originally asked the question about MonoDevelop, but I changed it when I saw it says that is Xamarin Studio in Help->About.

Comment: I just posted a link in the answer below. It's kind of dug down deep in the xamarin website. I myself had trouble finding it.

Answer (score 5):

Try upgrading to the latest version of Xamarin Studio (currently sitting at 6.x). I haven't had problems with LINQ in this one.

At this time the latest one has been 6.0.0.5174:

http://download.xamarin.com/studio/Windows/XamarinStudio-6.0.0.5174-0.msi

Here it is where to find it from your account:

[image]

Comment: When I start it, it gives me this error message - [Xamarin Studio 6.0 requires MSBuild Tools 2013 to be installed.](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/68582/did-anybody-else-get-xamarin-studio-failed-with-the-latest-update). I'll try installing them from https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-7/, as was suggested in the forum thread.

Comment: @sashoalm yep, just get them from here https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40760

Comment: I installed it but now I get the [Build Failed. See the build log for detail](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18837225/492336)

Comment: Is it possible that this error is because Xamarin 6.0 is not free and requires an account? One of the answers there mentions that you can get this error because you haven't logged into your account.

Comment: Xamarin is free since Microsoft bought it (at least to my knowledge ).  Not sure about the account problem though. Well you can create an account and log in ... worth giving it a shot i think.

Comment: OK. I was talking about http://stackoverflow.com/a/35556922/492336 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/36101827/492336 btw, they both say the problem was because of the account. I'll try logging in.