# Xamarin Studio can't build a console application

Tags: .net, windows, xamarin

My problem is similar to:

- [Xamarin Basics. Build Failed. See the build log for detail](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18837225)
- [Bug 37977 - C# consoleApp template doesn't build if .NET 4.5.1 is not installed (but 4.5 is)](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=37977)

but none of the solutions there help.

When creating a simple Console app and then building it, the IDE says:

> Error: Build failed. See the build log for details. (console)

And I can't find the build log.

The file in the log folder - `Ide*.log` file says:

> WARNING [2016-06-29 14:24:56Z]: Unregistered TargetFramework
>   '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.1' is being requested from
>   SystemAssemblyService, returning empty TargetFramework
>
> ERROR [2016-06-29 14:24:56Z]: Error while getting referenced assemblies
>   System.InvalidOperationException: No compatible framework found for assembly...
>
> --snip--

Isn't .NET v4.5.1 compatible with Xamarin Studio 6.0?

Answer (score 1):

Installing the ["Developer Pack" for .NET 4.5.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40772) fixed the issue for me as per this [discussion](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/61938/unregistered-targetframework-netframework-version-v4-5-1-is-being-requested-from). Then repair Xamarin (not Xamarin Studio).